# Different runtime for inner products of different size with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, performance

I discovered this interesting behavior of my numpy (M1 processor).
I did the following experiment: first I generated two random arrays of length 10^n, and then I computed their inner product.

```
powerof = 9 
r1 = np.random.rand(10**powerof) 
r2 = np.random.rand(10**powerof)
```

And then i compute the inner product, with

```
r1@ r2
```

This is the performance I measure:
10^8 = 0.8sec for generation, and 0.1sec  for inner product
10^9 = 10.8sec for generation, and 57sec for the inner product.

My question is the following:
Why the second time computing the inner product becomes slower than generating the random numbers? I was expecting something proportional to the case of 10^8, i.e. 1 second or something like that!

Comment: Do you have enough available memory? The 10^9 version takes 2 GiB of RAM. The OS may need to compress the memory or free/reload some caches. Do this behaviour occur with float32 arrays?